# Finding an analytic function satisfying given two conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Does there exists an analytic function $f:D\to D$ such that $f(1/2)=1/2$ and $f'(1/2)=-1$ ? If exists then find such a function. where , $D=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|<1\}.$

I found that such a function exists, as $$|f'(z)|\le \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}$$ holds good. But I am unable to find such a function..Please help to construct such a function.

Are there any particular rule to find such a function or it can be done only by trial ?

Comment: Have you tried polynomials?

Comment: I think you missed some part of the question then. You didn't say it should map circle to circle or specify what $D$ means.

Comment: Have you tried Mobius transformations?

Comment: If Mobius maps don't work, you might also apply the Riemann Mapping Theorem.

Comment: Well I know it transforms circles into circles or lines (circles on Riemann sphere). So I would start with finding out what is general form of Möbius transformation that maps unit circle into unit circle. If you manage to do that, the other two conditions will give you algebraic equations on coefficients. I don't know what are those equations so it remains for you to check if they have solutions.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 you should comment on the answer you get. the answerer seems to be sad just because of this! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Möbius Transformation: $\displaystyle \mu_a(z) = \frac{z - a}{1-\bar{a}z}$, for $|a| < 1$, it gives an injective mapping of $D = \{z: |z| < 1\}$ onto itself with inverse $\mu_{-a}(z)$,

satisfies $\mu_a'(0) = 1-|a|^2$ and $\displaystyle \mu_a'(a) = \frac{1}{1-|a|^2}$

As @Blazej commented, check that $\mu_a$ maps $\partial D$ onto itself.

Given an analytic function $f:D \to D$, with $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) =\frac{1}{2}$ and $\displaystyle f'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = -1$,

Define, $g(z) := \mu_{1/2}\circ f \circ \mu_{-1/2} (z)= \mu_{1/2}(f(\mu_{-1/2}(z)))$

Then $g$ maps $D$ into $D$ and satisfies $g(0) = 0$, and as a consequence of the Schwarz Lemma we infer that: $$|g'(0)| \le 1$$

Now, applying the chain rule see that:

$\displaystyle \begin{align} g'(0) &= (\mu_{1/2}\circ f)'(\mu_{-1/2}(0)).\mu'_{-1/2}(0) \\&= (\mu_{1/2}\circ f)'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).\mu'_{-1/2}(0)\\&= \mu'_{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)f'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{4}\right) = f'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = -1\end{align}$

This corresponds to the equality case in the Schwarz Lemma, hence $g$ must be of the form $$g(z) = -z$$ in $D$.

Hence, $$f(z) = \mu_{-1/2}\left(-\mu_{1/2}(z)\right).$$

Comment: How I construct $g$ ? It is only by inspection or there are any rule for construction of $g$ ?

Comment: @@r9m))Can you help me please ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response ,... Conjugation w.r.t. Mobius Transform is geometrically equivalent to taking inversion of a point w.r.t, a circle. The strategy was to show that in the extreme case (the equality case in the inequality you mentioned in the OP) corresponds to the case when the image of $f$ under conjugation by mobius transforms results in a straight line (a circle with infinite radius).

Comment: The method has been discussed in Conway's book, Functions in one complex variable (under Schwarz lemma and applications as far as I can remember)